# Create Recurring Outlook Calendar Event using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, outlook, calendar

I am trying to create Recurring event using Outlook Rest API in node.js for that I gone through documents whcihis provided by Microsoft but there is no sample example found  ,but I am getting error as

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
         "message": "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected."
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
 var jsonBody = {
      "Subject": "test event",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "sadsad"
        },
        "Start": "2016-05-27T00:00:00.000Z",
        "End": "2016-05-27T00:30:00.000Z",
        "Attendees": result,
         "Type":"Occurrence",
        "Recurrence": {
            "Pattern": {
                "DayOfMonth": 0,
                "Month": 0,
                "Type": "Daily",
                "Interval": 3,
                "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday"
            },
            "Range": {
                 "StartDate": "2015-05-27T00:00:00Z",
                "EndDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "NumberOfOccurrences": 0,
                "Type": "NoEnd"
            }
        }
    };

var optionsForCreatingcalendar = {                              
    uri: 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json: true,
    body: jsonBody,                
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    simple: false
};

// --- API call using promise-----
rp(optionsForCreatingcalendar)
.then(function(response) {  

},function(err){


});
```

Can some one help me resolve it?

Thanks in Adavnce.

Comment: Try to put numerical value for `Type` property in `Pattern` and `Range`. Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RecurrencePattern

Comment: Yes I tried by changing [ "Type": "Daily"    as  "Type":0,    and   "Type": "NoEnd"  as  "Type": 1 ] then also getting same Issue.

Comment: What's the content of `result` ?

Comment: result contains Email Address Array like this
 [{"EmailAddress":{"Name":"San Khavekar","Address":"khavekarsantosh@gmail.com"}}]

Comment: On each page i've found related to this error message, it's related to a bad "formatted" property.

Comment: Okay ,bad formatted property in the sense?

Comment: Such as bad types (string instead of int). In this example, dates are not formatted as yours: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents

Comment: can you give one date format?For example  I changed StartDate: "2015-05-23T00:00:00+05:30"  and  EndDate: "2015-06-23T00:00:00+03:00"as string and assigned in Range object,then also no use.so please suggest me to have correct date format for recurring .

Comment: @SantoshKhavekar do u have an idea how to create calender event using  express js?

Comment: Sorry I dont have idea on Express.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank god,I solved my problem.Because of Date format I was not able to create Event.

**Working Code:**

```
var jsonBody = {
      "Subject": "test event",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "sadsad"
        },
       "Start": {
                "DateTime": "2016-05-21T10:10:00",
                "TimeZone":"India Standard Time"
                },
        "End": {
                "DateTime":"2016-05-21T11:10:00",
                "TimeZone":"India Standard Time"
        },
        "Attendees": result,
         "Type":"Occurrence",
        "Recurrence": {
            "Pattern": {
                "DayOfMonth": 0,
                "Month": 0,
                "Type": "Daily",
                "Interval": 3,
                "FirstDayOfWeek": "Sunday"
            },
            "Range": {
                 "StartDate": "2016-05-27",
                "EndDate": "2016-06-27",
                "NumberOfOccurrences": 0,
                "Type": "NoEnd"
            }
        }
    };
```

Thank you All.

Comment: Hi Santosh, how did you get this token, am trying to get the token without authenticating with a Microsoft account as am doing that on the backend with node? Is there a way I can get the token without authenticating with a Microsoft account?

I tried using simple auth by following this guide

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050644/unable-to-exchange-auth-code-to-get-access-token-using-microsoft-identity-platfo

Comment: @sannimichaelse - this example has working code which gets working tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api